# In the backdrop of vs against the backdrop of

Tags: sentence-construction

I have generally seen **backdrop** in the following form: "against the backdrop of"

However, in an article I found the following sentence:

> > It is the story of a complex relationship and clashing ideologies between a father and son set **in the backdrop of** the kidnapping industry.

Is it the right way to use **backdrop** in this form: "in the backdrop of"?

Comment: No, it's wrong, You are right, backdrops are theatrical flats at the side or back of a stage. What is on stage, therefore, is seen against a backdrop and not in the backdrop. Writing in general seems to be deteriorating fast. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lambie comments, that sentence is incorrect. It's totally unambiguous, and when spoken it would go unnoticed, but it is wrong in writing.

Corrected:

> It is the story of a complex relationship and clashing ideologies between a father and son, set **against** the backdrop of the kidnapping industry.

(I've added a comma after "son", to break up the sentence. It's not required, but I prefer it.)